# About loving the one more than Allah SWT

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy, love

Recently I read one of Rumi poems but now I can't recall the name of that poem. In that poem, at last lines it was mentioned that the one who love another person more than Allah. Their love will be separated and they will not get what they want. The hatred will prevail in their hearts for each other... I might be wrong but the idea was totally as I mentioned... if anyone can elaborate. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I haven't read the poem myself .However I will answer your question to the best of my knowledge.

If a person loves another person for the sake of Allah , then Allah will love that person. The love of Allah is greater than the love your mother shows to you. There is nothing wrong with loving someone. If you love someone for Allah's Sake, it is equivalent to loving Allah.

As for loving Allah it can be achieved only by acknowledgING who he is; you have to understand who is Allah SWT . You can come to love Allah only through faith , fear and reverence for him.

Hope this helps

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, “None of you have faith until I am more beloved to him than his children, his father, and all of the people.”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 15, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 44

And our love for Allah should me more than that for Prophet(ﷺ).

May Allah forgive the writer of the poem (if he really wrote so) and give us the ability to love (and do all activities) according to the direction of Islam.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually looked at his poems so don't actually know this poem, however I will summarize it from the Islamic teachings

First of all, Allah teaches in The Qur'an that poem is forbidden in certain aspects in the same way that words are forbidden in certain aspects. If the poem teaches something immoral or bad; then it is haraam. However if the poem teaches something good and closeness to Allah then it is halaal. Similarly to how bad speech should be avoided and good words or speech is permissible.

Ibn Qudaamah said: There is no difference of opinion concerning the permissibility of poetry. This was stated by the Sahaabah and the scholars. Al-Mughni (10/176).
To find more rulings on poetry please see al-Mawsoo'ah al-Fiqhiyyah, 26/113-117.

Surah Shuaraa 26 ayahs 221-227 (its meaning): *221*. Shall I inform you (O people!) on whom it is that the Shayaateen descend? *222*. They descend on every lying, wicked person *223*. (Into whose ears) they pour hearsay, vanities; and most of them are liars. *224*. And the Poets, it is those straying in Evil who follow them: *225*. Seest thou not that they wander distracted in every valley? *226*. And that they say what they practice not? *227*. Except those who believe work righteousness, engage much in the remembrance of Allah and defend themselves only after they are unjustly attacked. And soon will the unjust assailants know what vicissitudes their affairs will take!

Now, on to loving a thing (including a person) more than loving Allah Himself. We should hate something (including a person) for the sake of Allah and we should hate a thing (including a person) for the sake of Allah and if we do so then that within itself is a part of the worship we have towards Allah and we through Allah's mercy can get rewarded for it. The same applies to anything we say and do, it should be merely for the sake of Allah and gaining His pleasure. If it's something of no benefit then we should abstain from it; likewise if it's something that brings us closer to Allah and thus Paradise then we should do it. We should hate a bad thing and love a good thing.

Al-Bukhaari (13), Muslim (45) and an-Nasaa'i (5017) narrated from Anas (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “By the One in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, no one of you truly believes until he loves for his brother what he loves for himself of good.”

Al-Haafiz ibn Hajar (may Allah have mercy on him) said: Al-Kirmaani said: It is also part of faith to hate for his brother what he hates for himself of evil. (Fat-h al-Baari [1/58])

Among the seven whom Allah will shade with His shade on the Day when there will be no shade but His are “two men who love one another for the sake of Allah, meeting and parting on that basis”, as it says in the saheeh hadith on which the scholars are agreed.

Ahmad (22002) narrated from ‘Ubaadah ibn as-Saamit that the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “[Allah says:] ‘My love is due for those who love one another for My sake; My love is due for those who visit one another for My sake; My love is due for those who help one another for My sake; My love is due for those whose hearts are free of grudges and who uphold ties with one another for My sake.’” Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami‘ (4321)

"If a heart becomes attached to anything other than Allah Ta'ala, Allah Ta'ala makes him dependent on what he is attached to. And he will be betrayed by it." Ibn Qayyim Al Jawziyyah.

So from the above you should have learned that we should love for the sake of Allah and hate for the sake of Allah, and that we should have love for Allah greater than love for anything else. But also that if our love for a thing is greater than our love for Allah then it will lead us into betrayal. So based on this, and if the poem referred to was encouraging greater love towards a thing than towards Allah then it is actually an haraam poem. May Allah forgive the writer of this and all of us for our shortcomings as no one is perfect and all of us needs forgiveness, some more than others, but all of us. Ameen.

And Allah knows best